# Is there a Snap option in the Graph Editor?

Tags: snapping, graph-editor

I want to move my vertice #2 up to the Y position of my vertice #1.

Is there a Snap option that would allow me to do it? I can't see it on the horizontal menu bar, perhaps I'm blind...

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks, it's done, and your method is actually simpler

Answer (score 2):

Ok so Mr Zak suggested me the best method to do it:

- Select the vertice #1 which is the Y position reference.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to make the cursor move to the vertice position.
- Select the 2D Cursor as the *Pivot Point*.
- Select all the vertices you want to snap to the Y position.
- Scale down to zero with <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

and a quite similar way:

- Select the vertice #1, which is your Y reference, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to move your green cursor up to this vertice.
- Select the vertices you want to align on the same Y position
- <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor Value to Selection*, and again <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Flatten Handles*, if necessary.